# Can a PFFile be stored/fetched from the local datastore if it is a property of a PFObject?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, local-datastore, pffile

I've seen some rumors/opinions on this, but does anyone know definitively if a PFFile can be stored/fetched to the datastore if it is a property of a PFObject?

For example, I have a class which is a subclassed PFObject.  Within the class, is a PFFile property:

```
@interface Stats : PFObject <PFSubclassing, NSCoding>
...
@property  PFFile *historyFile;
```

When I fetch the Stats object from the local data store, everything is retrieved, but this call:

```
NSData *data = [self.historyFile getData];
```

causes a crash:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[_NSPlaceholderData initWithContentsOfFile:options:error:]: nil file argument
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't store the file itself with pinning because PFFile does not have a pin() method.

You need to test for a successful save on the object and then store the file manually in your app if the object was successfully saved.

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28136535/1485715

Comment: Thanks!  Seen any best practices for dealing with no-internet situations and storing data locally that should get saved to PFFile eventually?