# Parse Local Data Store Inconsistency

Tags: ios, parse-platform, local-datastore

I am facing an inconsistency on Local Data Store on iOS , that 4 out of 10 attempt will be unable to retrieve the pinned data and get Error: This object is not available in the offline cache. When I request and pinned the data , it was available , but after few load, then the data was not able to retrieve, there is no code changes nor data updates, purely playing around offline. (I am unable to track this , because this occur inconsistently ).

Please kindly assist in troubleshooting this or suggest what should I do with it. I am using Local Data Store to store all major data of my app, and also did download the images related after pinned, I wonder is it because of storage limit by parse ? or something like auto clean out the pinned object ?

Answer (score 0):

You say that you are using Local Data Store for all the major data in your app. I presume you are using PFFile for the large data (like images), as per Parse's recommendation. If so, these do not persist in local datastore.

See here : [pffiles in local datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28132351/save-eventually-on-pfobject-with-pffile-parse-local-datastore)

Comment: My PFFile is there , but the Local Data Store data is missing / not found . the Cache of my PFFile is fine